# Where are the Hadoop Resource Manager metrics storage location?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

The Resource Manager REST API provides the status of all applications.

I'm curious to know where does this information is actually stored?

Is it possible to get this information to HBase/Hive?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot get this information from HBase or Hive because the Resource Manager REST APIs return live data from data structures in the RM.  The application logs are stored locally on Node Managers and in HDFS and Zookeeper maintains some state information that could be extracted independent of the RM but that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked on Timeline Server v2? ATSv2 can store all application metrics. As the storage this service uses HBase. (Link: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/TimelineServiceV2.html)

Check that ATSv2 supported in your version of Hadoop.